# 'Reading an unknown amount of values'? Unsure what to do

Tags: java

I need to make a program in Java that reads an unknown amount of values (integers), and when a negative value is entered, the loading shall stop.

I'm absolutely clueless about what I should do here, could someone please enlighten me?

Comment: share what are you doing. use `varargs` for unknown amount of values to be passed as method arguments.

Comment: From where will you read the integers? A text file, some online xml feed? from internet?

Comment: What I'm going to do is read these integers from inside the script. There are no specific numbers I'm talking about, just when they reach the negative number, it should stop, and sort the numbers from min to max.

Comment: If you are simply talking about the method that reads the number from lets say an array then just use a for loop to iterate over the numbers and and if statement that stops when you reach a negative value, after that you use what ever sorting algorithm you want (or Arrays.sort(array);) and you are done. My initial question was about how you retrieve these numbers but from what I understand you simply feed them into the program?

Comment: What I needed to do was to just retrieve an unknown amount of numbers (until it hits a negative one). So, to be exact this is what I know I'm working with "Create a program that reads an unspecified number of values ​​(integer). When the user enters a negative number should be the loading is completed." Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code :

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = in.nextInt();
        List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while(num>=0){
            lst.add(num);
            num = in.nextInt();
        }
        Collections.sort(lst);
        System.out.println("Sorted input : " + lst);
```

It takes input from console.

It takes input until a neg. no. is entered.(as you mentioned in your question)

It sorts the result after a neg. no. (as you mentioned in comment of your question)